# Let $H = \{x \in \mathbb C: x^{301} = 1\}$. Prove $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb C - \{0\}$ under multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $a, b \in H$, then $(ab)^{301} = a^{301}b^{301} = 1$ so that $ab \in H.$

But I am not sure about $(ab)^{301} = a^{301}b^{301}$. Is it allowed?

Comment: Is the multiplication in $\mathbb C$ commutative? That should answer the question.

Comment: This is allowed: complex numbers have this behaviour indeed.

Comment: It may be useful to observe that the equation $x^{301} = 1$ is a polynomial equation of degree $301$, so it has exactly $301$ solutions, namely $e^{2\pi i n / 301}$ for $n\in \{0,1,\ldots,300\}$.

Comment: Can you define a power homomorphism map between appropriate groups and then realize $H$ as its kernel?

Comment: @akech, sorry, no. But I thank everyone here.

Comment: For a guy who doesn't seem to know how to prove a subgroup doesn't it seem a bit difficult to ask him to define a homomorphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the one step test..
$a,b$ in $H$ and show $ab^{-1}$ is in $H$ 
Consider $$(ab^{-1})^{301}=a^{301}(b^{-1})^{301}=1.(b^{301})^{-1}=1.1=1$$

The fact that the indices have been taken inside is due to the commutativeness of $(C-${$0$}$,×) $